# Disable tag with ng-show but not content in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

Is it possible to just "disable" a tag instead of completly hiding it with its content? I want to enclose my content with the pre-tag only if a boolean is true. ng-show hides the complete tag with content if the boolean is false, but I only want to remove the pre-tag but keep the content. Is this possible?

My current solution is using a custom filter, but in my opinion this is more a hack than a solution.

```
angular.module("myApp", []).filter("myText", function ()
{
    return function (message)
    {
        message.text = message.text.trim();

        if (message.flag)
        {
            message.text = "<pre>" + message.text + "</pre>";
        }

        return message.text;
    };
});
```

Comment: You can do it in your html also. just post your html here.

Comment: What do you mean? I use html bootstrap and therefor need to use the pre-tag.

Comment: You can do this by using ui-if directive. For this, you need to have angular bootstrap library and I think you are using that only.

Answer (score 0):

Using a filter seems quite appropriate to be honest.

You can probably hack the html like this:

```
<span ng-hide="message.flag"><pre></span>{{message}}<span ng-hide="message.flg"></pre></span>
```

The W3 validator seems to be down so I can't verify this is valid html but even if it is, I wouldn't use this solution :)

Comment: Thanks, but you are right. I wouldn't use that too! Thanks anyway :)